# How to add xrdp server in yocto?

Tags: yocto, raspberry-pi4, xrdp

I am working on raspberry pi 4 and install a yocto linux image on that.

Is there any way to add xrdp server in yocto warrior branch?

I have added recepie from meta-openembedded/meta-oe/recepie-support/rxdp/
In final image but can't get remote desktop of raspberry pi

[please find logs from here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cqXLP.png)

[logs of journalctl command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eweo9.png)

Thanks
Margish

Answer (score 1):

```
IMAGE_INSTALL += " xrdp "
```

Comment: thanks @Oleksandr Kravchuk

I have already tried that but xrdp service failed every time to start

I have also run this command
systemctl show -p SubState --value xrdp
but it gives failed every time

currently I have only tty console in my yocto image(i.e no desktop support)

Comment: thanks for your support @Oleksandr Kravchuk, please find log below. here I'm posting 2 comments due to characters limit in comment

● xrdp.service - xrdp daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/xrdp.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2021-06-15 10:01:28 EDT; 2 days ago
     Docs: man:xrdp(8)
           man:xrdp.ini(5)
  Process: 227 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/xrdp $XRDP_OPTIONS (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Comment: Jun 15 10:01:28 raspberrypi4 systemd[1]: Starting xrdp daemon...
Jun 15 10:01:28 raspberrypi4 systemd[1]: xrdp.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jun 15 10:01:28 raspberrypi4 systemd[1]: xrdp.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jun 15 10:01:28 raspberrypi4 systemd[1]: Failed to start xrdp daemon.

Comment: Add logs for the service to your question - it's impossible to read them.

Comment: please find logs in my question. @Oleksandr Kravchuk
Thanks in advance

Comment: sorry for the delay @Oleksandr Kravchuk.

please find required logs in question

Comment: I think desktop is required in yocto image to run xrdp.service @Oleksandr Kravchuk.

Comment: please give your input if you have any idea- @Oleksandr Kravchuk

Comment: I thought you've figured it out - you are missing GUI

Comment: what should I add for GUI ?, currently im using Qt application and it's working fine on current image @Oleksandr Kravchuk

Comment: Did you get a chance to see my last comment ?@Oleksandr Kravchuk